# Replace single quote " with double quote "" using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have never used XML/XSLT/JScript before, and am very quickly trying to learn.

I am creating a CSV file using XSLT 1.0 and XML. I have got the below code, created by an external software developer who cannot help currently, which works fine and does as is required, except for one issue. I need to replace all occurrences of a single quote character " with double quote characters "", to ensure correct escape of the quote character.

```
>   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
xmlns:mxm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/MxmServInterfaceOutboundAif" 
xmlns:data="http://www.maxima.com/data" exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsi xsl">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" /> 
 <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="data">
 <![CDATA[
function convertDate(dt)
  {     
    var yy = dt.substr(6, 2);
    var mm = dt.substr(3, 2);
    var dd = dt.substr(0, 2);
    var ret = "20"+yy+mm+dd;

    return ret.toString();  
  }    

  function convertTime(dt)
  {     
    var ss = dt.substr(6, 2);
    var mm = dt.substr(3, 2);
    var hh = dt.substr(0, 2);
    var ret = hh+mm+ss;

    return ret.toString();  
  }

  function IncidentType(fault)
  {
    var type = fault.substr(0,2);
    if (type == "PM")
      {
      var ret = "MAINTENANCE";
      }
      else
      {
      var ret = "CALLOUT";
      }

    return ret;                           
  }


]]> 
</msxsl:script>
 <xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="Visit" /> 
</xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/Visit/MxmServCallVisit">

"Incident_ID","Incident_Type","Created_Date","Created_Time","Notes"
" 
<xsl:value-of select="./JobId" /> 
"," 
<xsl:value-of select="data:IncidentType(string(./MxmServCall/FaultId))" /> 
"," 
<xsl:value-of select="data:convertDate(string(./MxmServCall/LoggedDate))" /> 
"," 
<xsl:value-of select="data:convertTime(string(./MxmServCall/LoggedTime))" /> 
"," 
<xsl:value-of select="./Instructions" /> 
" 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can someone advise how I create a function to apply to the Instructions field, which would search through the Instructions field and either add a preceding double quote wherever there is an existing double quote, or replace existing quote with two double quotes?

For example, if Instructions field contains:

```
I have been told to "Go to site asap"
```

I want to replace this with:

```
I have been told to ""Go to site asap""
```

I have gone through this site, and others, to see if there is something I can use. The only thing I have found a lot is using a REPLACE function which I believe cannot be used with XSLT 1.0. Also, a lot of people are recommending to use a recursive template, but I have no idea how to use it or follow the examples provided for it. I need to spend some time trying to figure it out, but I have a deadline which means I have no more time left to try to figure it out myself. Is it possible to use a function to carry out this task?

All help most appreciated

Comment: Just as a quick heads up - avoid copying XML from MSIE (or most web browsers), as it adds `-` before records, which in this case invalidates your style sheet.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that. I saw them there, but wasnt sure whether they were part of the stylesheet or not. I have now removed them. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as you already use JScript I assume you can add another function

```
function replace(string, regexPattern, repl) {
  return string.replace(new RegExp(regexPattern, 'g'), repl);
}
```

inside the JScript section and then do

```
<xsl:value-of select="data:replace(string(Instructions), '&quot;', '&quot;&quot;')" />
```

Comment: Hi @Martin I have tried your code suggested. There is a problem. Only the first occurrence of a quote is replaced by a double quote within the string. eg if my original string is:

 `test quote "quoted text", "blah blah", ","`

I want it to be returned as:

`test quote ""quoted text"", ""blah blah"", "",""`

However, I am getting the following:

`test quote ""quoted text", "blah blah", ","`

Do you have any further advice? Many thanks for your help

Comment: I have edited the JScript code to explicitly construct a `RegExp` object with the `g` flag for global searches/replaces which hopefully fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much @Martin, that is awesome!!